# Using regex to Retrieve multiple data from Mongodb

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to Mongodb

Here is what i have tried. however this method worked for me but its way slow.
Is it possible to design single query to get all this data. instead of querying one by one.

```
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;// Schema
 var dataModelSchema = new Schema({
data: String,
});

var fdevices = mongoose.model('fdevices', dataModelSchema);
var DPMPow = fdevices.findOne({ "Data": { $regex: /DPMPow_P01/i } }).sort({ 
field: 'asc', _id: -1 }); //Active Power 
var DPMAmp = fdevices.findOne({ "Data": { $regex: /DPMAmp_P01/i } }).sort({ 
field: 'asc', _id: -1 });//Total Current
var DPMkWh = fdevices.findOne({ "Data": { $regex: /DPMkWh_P01/i } }).sort({ 
field: 'asc', _id: -1 });//Consumption
var MxPeak = fdevices.findOne({ "Data": { $regex: /MxPeak_P01/i } }).sort({ 
field: 'asc', _id: -1 });//Max Demand Peak
var MPPeak = fdevices.findOne({ "Data": { $regex: /MPPeak_P01/i } }).sort({ 
field: 'asc', _id: -1 });//Max Demand Partial

   async.series([
    function (callback) {
        DPMPow.exec(function (err, res) {
            callback(null, res);
        })
    },
    function (callback) {
        DPMAmp.exec(function (err, res) {
            callback(null, res);
        });
    },
    function (callback) {
        DPMkWh.exec(function (err, res) {
            callback(null, res);
        })

    },
    function (callback) {
        MxPeak.exec(function (err, res) {
            callback(null, res);
        })

    }, function (callback) {
        MPPeak.exec(function (err, res) {
            callback(null, res);
        })
        //chiller1
    }
 ], function (err, results) {
           console.log(results);
 });
```

this is how my data looks like in database. in collection got only one field which name as 'Data' this field receives multiple sensors data in every one hour.

```
 { _id: 5b2118c4ae33249711a498a6,
  Data: '13-06-2018 20:14:46 DPMPow_P01_04_ 699.15 ',
  __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5b2118c4ae35439711a498a6,
  Data: '13-06-2018 20:14:46 MPPeak_P01_04_ 699.15 ',
  __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5b23428c4ae32989711a498a6,
   Data: '13-06-2018 20:14:46 DPMAmp_P01_04_ 699.15 ',
  __v: 0 },
    { _id: 5b21234c4ae32989711a498a6,
    Data: '13-06-2018 20:14:46 DPMkWh_P01_04_ 699.15 ',
   __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5b2118c4ae34989711a598a6,
    Data: '13-06-2018 20:14:46 MxPeak_P01_04_ 699.15 ',
  __v: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below RegEx in find query

```
let data = fdevices.find({ "Data": { $regex: /(DPMPow)|(MPPeak)|(DPMAmp)|(DPMkWh)| 
  (MxPeak)/gm } }).sort({ field: 'asc', _id: -1 });
```

Comment: Please format code lines as a "code" when you are submitting an answer or question. Please refer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks